# C# form inheritance - Function in parent form needs to call overrided function in child

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Ok - I've hit a problem that I'm having a difficult time solving.

I've got two forms - one inherits from the other.  We'll call them FormParent and FormChild.

MyFunction() is defined in FormParent.  I don't need to override it as it will do the same basic thing for lots of different forms, but it calls DoSomethingUnique().  DoSomethingUnique is defined in the parent and overridden in the child.

My problem is that since I'm not overriding MyFunction(), when I call it from FormChild the version of DoSomethingUnique() that it calls is the function from FormParent, not FormChild.

Is there any way to avoid overriding both functions but have the version of DoSomethingUnique() that's called be the version from FormChild?

Comment: The situation you are describing does not sound correct. If `MyFunction()` calls `DoSomethingUnique()` and `DoSomethingUnique()` is overridden, then the overridden version should be invoked. Please show us some actual code, or an analogous example of your actual code.

Comment: Don't you have to call an `override` with a `virtual`? I may be missing something...

Comment: @Brian Yes, you do, but user2848780 has said that s/he is overriding the method. Of course, we won't know for sure what the situation is unless we see the code.

Comment: @JLRishe - I completely agree.  Although, I suspect that we won't see that come to fruition...

Comment: The technical detail for this is that if `DoSomethingUnique()` isn't marked up as virtual, the emitted IL for `MyFunction(){DoSomethingUnique();}` will be a `call` rather than a `callvirt`, and will thus be dispatched to the `FormParent` `DoSomethingUnique()`.

Comment: Sorry guys - when I tried to put in an actual code snippet the formatting was going awry and so I just put in the text description.  The problem was indeed in explicitly stating the "virtual" and "override".  Its been ~10 years since I did any significant OO programming and I thought that overriding a function was implicit (ie, just define it in the child class).  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting to do will certainly work.  You just need to make sure you have the correct modifiers in place.

In FormParent..

```
virtual public void DoSomethingUnique()
```

In FormChild

```
override public void DoSomethingUnique()
```

If you don't explicitly modify the method with `override` then you will be calling the method in FormParent.

Obviously replace void with your return type.